# Embed webbrowser control inside IE

Tags: internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, activexobject

How can I create a web browser activeX object inside a HTML document that is being opened with IE?

I have tried something like this, but the object did not display:

```
<object id="mini" width=300 height=300 classid="CLSID_WebBrowser"</object> ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSDN, since IE6 you should use an `iframe` instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752044%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

That said, the following "works" for me in IE11. You have to specify the value of `CLSID_WebBrowser`:

```
<object classid="clsid:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2" id="browser" width="600" height="600" />
```

You can then do e.g.

```js
document.getElementById("browser").navigate("http://www.example.com")
```

**Edit:** However, after the first navigate, any other method calls or property accesses result in "access denied". This is apparently by design: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/176789

Then IE crashes when I close it so YMMV. I think the lesson here is that this isn't supported and you probably shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: It's working but there is one problem. Since I can't use javascript, is it possible to make it navigate to a page right after being loaded? Something like 
<object classid="clsid:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2" id="browser" width="600" height="600"><param name="Url" value="http://google.com"></object> ?

Comment: Found it. Param name is "Location"